# Who was Wright, purportedly the best player in the Australian prison system?

Tags: history, books

I read a true crime book by Mark "Chopper". It states the best player in the Australian prison system was named Wright. Does anyone have any more information on this person, such as their first name?

Answer (score 4):

His name was [Robert Wright](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Chopper_Unchopped/NjWgeUz7E5gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22finest%20chess%22&pg=PT274&printsec=frontcover), a convicted murderer who died in a [1987 prison fire](https://www.heraldsun.com.au/news/law-order/coroners-inquiry-examined-who-was-at-fault-in-the-1987-fatal-fire-in-the-jika-jika-section-of-pentridge-prison/news-story/0b949d92c9beaaf2e36ead7cd477c551).